# Type Script error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. in ionic application

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Good day, everyone. I am facing this problems in my project which is Type Script error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. This error make me cannot create a select the other option for custom input pop up. In this forum, I have post the typescript code and error part of the typecript code.
[The error code of the typescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Zz6.png)

Typescript Code

```
 import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
  import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

  constructor(
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public alertController: AlertController
  ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
      this.religions = [
          "Islam",
          "Buddha",
          "Hinduism",
          "Christian",
          "Sikhism",
          "Taiosm",
          "Other"
        ];
        
        this.currentReligionValue = "Islam";
      
        this.validations_form = this.formBuilder.group({
        religion: new FormControl(this.currentReligionValue, Validators.required),
    });
    }

      validation_messages = {
    'religion': [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Religion is required to select' },
  };

  //When have other values
  selectChanged(selected) {
    if (selected === 'Other') {
      this.inputValue();
    } else {
      this.currentvalue = selected;
    };
  };
```

The error part in the TypeScript

```
async inputValue() {
        const inputAlert = await this.alertController.create({
          header: 'Enter your custom color:',
          inputs: [ { type: 'text', placeholder: 'type in' } ],
          buttons: [ { text: 'Cancel' }, { text: 'Ok' } ]
        });
      inputAlert.onDidDismiss((data) => { //<-- The error part is starting here
          let customName: string = data.data.values[0];
          if (customName) {
            let indexFound = this.religions.findIndex(religion => religion === customName)
            if (indexFound === -1) {
              this.religions.push(customName);
              this.currentReligionValue = customName;
            } else {
              this.currentReligionValue = this.religions[indexFound];
            };
          };      
        }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
        await inputAlert.present();
      };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert#methods), the method `onDidDismiss<T = any>()` does not take any parameter.
It returns a `Promise` of `OverlayEventDetail<T>` that resolves when the alert did dismiss.

The following code should work just fine.

```js
const inputAlert = await this.alertController.create({...});
inputAlert.onDidDismiss()
  .then((event: OverlayEventDetail) => event.data...)
  .catch(console.log);
```

You can type the method if you want auto-completion when accessing the data in the callback.

Comment: Hi, Reqven, your answer is very useful to me. Thank you.